# Erro muito estranho ao fazer queries com o pg no typescript

Tags: node.js, postgresql, typescript

Eu estou fazendo um projeto de api muito simples com typescript sem nenhum ORM, fazendo as queries na raça mesmo só com o módulo de integração do postgres com  typescrit mesmo. O que acontece é que as queries simplesmente não funcionam nas funções do meu repositório, o que é muito estranho, já quem em outro projeto com exatamente o mesmo código funciona normalmente. Inicialmente pensei que seria um problema na conexão do banco de dados, mas as mutations rodam perfeitamente e como disse, em meu outro projeto com as mesmas versões dos módulos tudo funciona normalmente. O erro é o seguinte:

```shell
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'query')
    at TesteRepository.showUsers (/home/tapes-arch/Repositories/expenses-control/testes.ts:13:40)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/tapes-arch/Repositories/expenses-control/testes.ts:21:17)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1105:14)
    at Module.m._compile (/home/tapes-arch/Repositories/expenses-control/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:1618:23)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1159:10)
    at Object.require.extensions.<computed> [as .ts] (/home/tapes-arch/Repositories/expenses-control/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:1621:12)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:827:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:77:12)
    at phase4 (/home/tapes-arch/Repositories/expenses-control/node_modules/ts-node/src/bin.ts:649:14)
```

Para facilitar criei um repositório de teste apenas para isolar e tentar encontrar o problema, mas sem sucesso também, segue o código:

```js
import { createDatabaseConnection } from './src/database/connectDatabase'
import { Pool } from 'pg'

class TesteRepository {
  private client: Pool
  constructor() {
    createDatabaseConnection().then(connection => (this.client = connection))
  }

  async showUsers() {
    const { rows } = await this.client.query('SELECT * FROM USERS')

    console.log(rows)
  }
}

const testeRepository = new TesteRepository()

testeRepository.showUsers()
```

O arquivo responsável por conectar no banco de dados:

```js
import 'dotenv/config'
import { Pool } from 'pg'

export const createDatabaseConnection = async () => {
  const client = new Pool({
    host: process.env.PGHOST,
    user: process.env.PGUSER,
    password: process.env.PGPASSWORD,
    database: process.env.PGDATABASE,
    port: parseInt(process.env.PGPORT)
  })

  await client.connect()

  return client
}
```

O banco de dados está criado e as mutations estão rodando corretamente, sinal que a conexão está sendo feita sem erros, ao rodar queries diretamente pelo cliente do postgres tudo funciona, eu tenho dúvidas inclusive da onde está vindo o problema, já vasculhei toda a internet e não achei esse tipo de problema em lugar nenhum.

Comment: Um pouco complicado e, pelo que sempre vi, não se deve usar operações assíncrona em métodos construtores de classes. Algumas alternativas são sugeridas como criar um `static factory functions` que ficaria responsável por criar a conexão com o banco de dados ou nesse caso, receber o `connection` como parâmetro no construtor.

Comment: Antes de rodar a query, você pode dar um ```console.log(this.client)``` pra gente ver o que é? Estou suspeitando que assíncrono, sua função ```showUsers``` esteja rodando antes de o construtor fixar o ```this.client```.

Comment: @CésarRodriguez fiz isso e o resultado foi `this.client:undefined`, talvez o problema esteja mesmo aí. A minha dúvida fica apenas em por que no meu outro projeto não está dando o mesmo erro, pois usei a mesma abordagem.

Answer (score -2):

Tudo indica que seu problema é um efeito colateral de usar construtores dependentes de  valores assíncronos (veja [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43433773/11379709), como apontado por Augusto).
Achei um padrão interessante para contornar construtores assíncronos [nesse site](https://dev.to/somedood/the-proper-way-to-write-async-constructors-in-javascript-1o8c). Basicamente, você criará um *factory* a ser usado no lugar do construtor, que será um método estático de sua classe. Deixei um aviso no construtor para alertar ao usuário que não pode ser instanciado dessa forma.

Assim:

```js
import { createDatabaseConnection } from './src/database/connectDatabase'
import { Pool } from 'pg'

class TesteRepository {
  private client: Pool
  constructor(conn: Pool) { // Adapte para colocar o tipo, eu inferi pela propriedade client
    if (!conn) {
      throw "A classe TesteRepository só deve ser instanciada através do método estático 'TesteRepository.createClient()', ou recebendo uma conexão como parâmetro."
    }
    this.client = conn
  }

  static async createClient() {
    this.client = await createDatabaseConnection()
    return new TesteRepository(this.client)
  }

  async showUsers() {
    const { rows } = await this.client.query('SELECT * FROM USERS')

    console.log(rows)
  }
}

const testeRepository = await TesteRepository.createClient()
testeRepository.showUsers()
```

Veja se funciona para você.

Comment: Mas a função arrow tem escopo léxico -- ela não vai criar um escopo próprio, mantendo o do lugar onde foi chamada -- acho que o ```this.client``` aí dentro aponta para a propriedade client mesmo: https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#sem_liga%C3%A7%C3%A3o_binding_de_argumentos_arguments

Comment: O escopo modificaria se ele usasse uma função anônima normal, algo como ```createDatabaseConnection().then(function(connection) { this.client = connection })```.

Comment: Fiquei curioso! Vou fazer um teste num codepen, pera (vou ter que reiniciar antes por causa de um driver que acabei de instalar).

Comment: Olha só uma simulação do código original (que me faz crer que o problema é de sincronia, e demonstra que não é de escopo): https://codepen.io/ironsand-sou-eu/pen/zYaJqPm?editors=1011
Já aqui, uma simulação da minha resposta: https://codepen.io/ironsand-sou-eu/pen/rNKZeed?editors=1111

Comment: Ou melhor: os codepens não necessariamente resolvem o problema dele, mas mostram que é bem fundada a suspeita de se tratar de uma propriedade ainda ```undefined``` porque está aguardando o retorno de uma operação assíncrona.

Comment: Estive lendo [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43433773/11379709) que promises não devem ser usadas em constructors pois constructors devem retornar um objeto construído e não uma promessa de um objeto a ser construído. Como solução o autor da resposta sugeriu um object factory que é basicamente o código que escreveu em `static async createClient()`. Dá uma analisada como o autor da resposta a redigiu pois está muito bem escrita e agrega valor a pergunta e ao site.